# Any way to use React refs with methods on the window object that require DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, twitter

I'm writing a React app that embeds lists of Tweets that it pulls from an API. I'm aware that there already exists `react-twitter-embed` and `react-twitter-widgets` but both of these proved to be very slow, both in terms of load time and visual performance when scrolling, compared to Twitter's own `twttr` [javascript widgets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/set-up-twitter-for-websites).

The only problem with using Twitter's widget is that, in order to implement lazy loading such that the app does not actually make the call to Twitter's embed API until the div containing the Tweet is visible on the screen, it seems I have to do some direct DOM references which I understand is not good to do in React.

The "React-flavored" version I attempted first looked something like this:

`Tweet component`

```js
const tweetDOMId = `twt-${tweet.twtId}`
const divDOMId = `div-${tweet.twtId}`
const tweetRef = createRef()

<div id={divDOMId} ref={tweetRef}>
  <blockquote
    id={tweetDOMId}
    className='twitter-tweet'
    data-dnt='true'
    data-theme='dark'>
    <a href={twtUrl}></a>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

`Parent component`

```js
const loadTweet = (tweetRef) => {
        window.twttr.widgets.load(tweetRef)
        window.twttr.events.bind('rendered', (event) => {
            setLoadedTweet(event.target.(...).tweetId)
        })
    }
```

However, the Twitter `widgets.load()` method was unable to find the appropriate element to turn into an embedded tweet this way. Instead, I had to write it like this:

`Tweet component`

```js
const tweetDOMId = `twt-${tweet.twtId}`

  <blockquote
    id={tweetDOMId}
    className='twitter-tweet'
    data-dnt='true'
    data-theme='dark'>
    <a href={twtUrl}></a>
  </blockquote>
```

`Parent component`

```js
const loadTweet = (elementId) => {
        window.twttr.widgets.load(document.getElementById(`${elementId}`))
        window.twttr.events.bind('rendered', (event) => {
            setLoadedTweet(event.target.(...).tweetId)
        })
    }
```

So I am wondering if there is any way to not use `document.getElementById()` in this situation? A way to supply `window.twttr.widgets.load()` with a reference to the element that it needs without querying the DOM?

Using `document.getElementById()` is what [Twitter recommends](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization), but that example in the link is clearly for vanilla js, not React.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to load the ref directly, instead of `ref.current`.